# I would like an update for this old question: Should I use a bounty or a new question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates, bounty

I have asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178211/would-a-racial-feature-that-lets-you-learn-a-low-level-spell-of-your-choice-be-b) some years ago.

It is about giving spells as a racial feature in [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e). The answer is good but racial features of the kind have significantly changed in official publications (most notably, these spells can now also be cast with class spell slots) and I would like some analysis that considers this.

**What is the right way to go about this? A bounty on the old questions or a new question?**

Answer (score 9):

#### Bounty seems right, here.

"Current answers are outdated" is a standard bounty reason, followed by the description "the current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes." Seems like it fits your question exactly!

If recent changes had undercut or modified the premises of your *question* in a significant way, I might suggest posting a new question and closing the old as a duplicate of the new--but it doesn't seem to me that's what's going on.